# Run a Shortcode from a Button in Visual Composer - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, visual-composer

This should be a fairly obvious thing to be able to do. I have a plugin that has a modal newsletter signup form. I am very happy with the plugin and it has a number of options for the way it launches (after x seconds, when user reaches bottom of screen etc) it also has a manual launch option which gives me these following codes.

[image]

My theme uses Visual Composer. I want to launch the popup manually when a site user clicks a button on the homepage. I thought this would be simple but apparently not. The options I have with the standard VC button is shown below; I have tried numerous options of adding classes to the button but I cannot add a shortcode or class to any of the fields to launch the modal. I know there is a javascript onClick function but I'm not very good with Javascript. There must be a simple way to click a button and open a modal, maybe I am overlooking something completely obvious.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK after reading back my question I thought about adding a custom css class to the button field Extra Class Name and it works. I thought that the extra class name here was for styling the button itself and did not realise that this would also trigger the pop-up as well. Guess I should have checked that first.